# Embedded JSON to Swift

Tags: json, swift, decode, jsondecoder

I'm very new to using swift and decoding JSON. I'm trying to make a pokedex-type app and am using a JSON feed to read from.

The JSON Feed:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "english": "Bulbasaur",
      "japanese": "フシギダネ",
      "chinese": "妙蛙种子",
      "french": "Bulbizarre"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 45,
      "Attack": 49,
      "Defense": 49,
      "Sp. Attack": 65,
      "Sp. Defense": 65,
      "Speed": 45
    }
  },

//More entries

]
```

My Approach:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var pokemonInfo = GetData()

    var body: some View {
        List(pokemonInfo.pokemon){
            pokemon in
            Text(pokemon.name.english)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Pokemon: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: Name
    public var type: [String]
    public var base: Base
}

struct Name: Codable {
    public var english: String
    public var japanese: String
    public var chinese: String
    public var french: String
}

struct Base: Codable {
    public var hp: Int
    public var attack: Int
    public var defense: Int
    public var sp_attack: Int
    public var sp_defense: Int
    public var speed: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case hp = "HP"
        case attack = "Attack"
        case defense = "Defense"
        case sp_attack = "Sp. Attack"
        case sp_defense = "Sp. Defense"
        case speed = "Speed"
    }
}

public class GetData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pokemon = [Pokemon]()
    init(){
        load()
    }

    func load(){
        let dataUrl = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fanzeyi/pokemon.json/master/pokedex.json")!
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dataUrl) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try decoder.decode([Pokemon].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.pokemon = decodedLists
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

When I try to simply display the id of each pokemon in a list view, each entry is blank which leads me to believe I have messed up somewhere in decoding the JSON feed.

Comment: I think you need to write custom coding keys for `Base` structure. (Sp. Attack, Sp. Defense) is not valid

Comment: Okay I will try that

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Try putting a breakpoint where you receive data, try finding a place where it breaks. Log could also help identify the problem.

Comment: I have it working now. I think my solution up there does actually work, I think my problem was with XCode and not my code